# I can't see the 4th option in Distribute Android apps in your organization document

Tags: android, google-play

I want to distribute the application in my organization with private channel.
I have Google Apps account (i.e., @***.com, not @gmail.com). I have followed the instructions described at "[Distribute Android apps in your organization](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992)" up to step 3 but I can't see the 4th option. Can anyone guild me?

[image: Distribute Android apps in your organization]

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow and as such, should be closed despite opened bounty.